# Connection and parse MiBand3 on Windows

Tags: python

The task: connect to the MiBand3 bracelet via Bluetooth on a PC, parse some data from it, and output these values somewhere (for example, on a website, it doesn't matter). I am trying to accomplish this in Python on Windows OS. Please suggest methods of connection, libraries, or effective alternatives.

The libraries bluepy and pygatt are not supported on Windows. There have been many unsuccessful attempts to use PyBluez and bleak.